# Iterate to sequential position in boost::multi_index by size_t index?

Tags: c++, boost

I've just started to use boost multi_index and so far have a container that consits of a sequenced type and composite key unorderd hashes.

What I want to do is access the sequenced container as if it were a std::vector or std::list. By this I mean by means of using `size_t index`.

Here is my code below:

```
// tags
struct linear { };
struct semantic { };
struct semantic_and_index { };

// typedefs for multi_index
typedef boost::multi_index::sequenced< 
    boost::multi_index::tag<linear>
> LinearIndex;

typedef boost::multi_index::composite_key<
    CVertexElement,
    boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<CVertexElement, Buffer::VertexSemantic, &CVertexElement::GetVertexSemantic>,
    boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<CVertexElement, UInt, &CVertexElement::GetSemanticIndex> 
> CompositeSemanticIndex;

typedef boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique<
    boost::multi_index::tag<semantic_and_index>,
    CompositeSemanticIndex
> SemanticAndIDIndex;

typedef boost::multi_index::hashed_non_unique<
    boost::multi_index::tag<semantic>,
    boost::multi_index::const_mem_fun<CVertexElement, Buffer::VertexSemantic, &CVertexElement::GetVertexSemantic> 
> SemanticIndex;

class CVertexFormat
{
public:
    typedef boost::multi_index::multi_index_container <
        CVertexElementPtr,
        boost::multi_index::indexed_by <
            LinearIndex,
            SemanticAndIDIndex,
            SemanticIndex
        > // index_by
    > ElementContainer; 

      // etc...

protected:
    ElementContainer m_elements;
};
```

The function I am referring to is:

```
// this function fails! :(
CVertexElementPtr CVertexFormat::GetElement(size_t index) const 
{
    //sequenced_index.
    typedef ElementContainer::index<linear>::type element_by_linear;
    const element_by_linear& index_type = m_elements.get<linear>();

    if ( index < index_type.size() )
    {
        auto itor = index_type.begin();
        for (UInt i = 0; i < index_type.size(); ++i)
            ++itor;

        const CVertexElementPtr& pElement = (*itor);        
        return pElement;
    }
    else
    {
        assert(!"Invalid index called for GetElement");
        return CVertexElementPtr();
    }
}
```

Picture of the error in vs2010 (look at the watch window on the right):

[High res screen shot](http://cid-7270631df3d4ec84.photos.live.com/self.aspx/Web%20Site/Screenshot.jpg)

Comment: What exactly fails? What error are you getting?

Comment: The iterator is invalid for some reason. When I debug the application it says there are **2 nodes** within the `m_elements`. However with `index = 0` the `itor` returned from `index_type.begin()` is invalid... I don't know how it can be invalid? I'll attach a screen shot to the question if I can also.

Comment: Actually I just solved it. It was the `for (UInt i = 0; i < index_type.size(); ++i)`. It should actually be `for (UInt i = 0; i < index; ++i)`. Seems that cup of coffee actually worked for me.

Comment: so post this as an answer from yourself, and accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by changing the function `CVertexElementPtr CVertexFormat::GetElement(size_t index) const`.

The correct function is:

```
CVertexElementPtr CVertexFormat::GetElement(size_t index) const
{
    //sequenced_index.
    typedef ElementContainer::index<linear>::type element_by_linear;
    const element_by_linear& index_type = m_elements.get<linear>();

    size_t size = index_type.size();
    if ( index < size )
    {
        auto itor = index_type.begin();
        for (UInt i = 0; i < index; ++i)
            ++itor;

        const CVertexElementPtr& pElement = (*itor);        
        return pElement;
    }
    else
    {
        assert( false && ieS("Invalid index called for GetElement") );
        return CVertexElementPtr();
    }
}
```